# Segfault when creating smartpointer on CairoContext

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, cairo, gtkmm

I got some problems when creating a Cairo::RefPtr on a Cairo-Context.
I really can't imagine why this segfaults, except the pointer ist pointing on something completely wrong.

This is my code.

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[])
    {
    Gtk::Main kit(argc, argv);
    Gtk::Window window;
    Gtk::DrawingArea drawarea;
    window.add(drawarea);
    Cairo::RefPtr<Cairo::Context> ccontext = drawarea.get_window()->create_cairo_context();
    Gtk::Allocation allocation = drawarea.get_allocation();
    const int width = allocation.get_width();
    const int height = allocation.get_height();
    ccontext->set_source_rgb(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    ccontext->set_line_width(2.0);
    ccontext->move_to(0,0);
    ccontext->line_to(width, height);

    Gtk::Main::run(window);

    }
```

And this is what GDB says:

> Starting program: /home/marian/Desktop/C++/Langton/Langton  [Thread
>   debugging using libthread_db enabled]
>
> Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault. 0xb7be852e in
>   Gdk::Window::create_cairo_context() () from /usr/lib/libgdkmm-3.0.so.1

I compiled this with gcc (GCC) 4.6.1 20110819 (prerelease).

Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe I should provide more information. This is more or less directly from the gtkmm reference, the code should be correct.
I compiled it with : `g++ main.cc -g -o Langton `pkg-config --cflags --libs cairomm-1.0 gtkmm-3.0` ` This was compiled on Arch Linux with Gtkmm3.2.0-1 and Cairomm-1.10.0-1 installed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gtk::Widget::get_window() returns a null Glib::RefPtr, since the widget has not been realized just yet.

Based on the [GtkDrawingArea documentation](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/3.2/GtkDrawingArea.html), you need to hook onto the "draw" signal to handle drawing, where your Cairo context is already created and handed to you. Going back to the [Gtkmm reference](http://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm/unstable/classGtk_1_1Widget.html), you would use Gtk::Widget::signal_draw() to hook onto that, or you could overload the virtual on_draw() function to handle your drawing.

Additionally, you also need to call .show() on each widget, i.e. your DrawingArea and your Window, and call ccontext->stroke() to get the line actually drawn.

The result would look something like:

```
#include <gtkmm.h>

bool draw (const Cairo::RefPtr<Cairo::Context> &ccontext, Gtk::DrawingArea *drawarea)
{
    Gtk::Allocation allocation = drawarea->get_allocation();
    const int width = allocation.get_width();
    const int height = allocation.get_height();
    ccontext->set_source_rgb(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    ccontext->set_line_width(2.0);
    ccontext->move_to(0,0);
    ccontext->line_to(width, height);
    ccontext->stroke ();

    return true;
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    Gtk::Main kit(argc, argv);
    Gtk::Window window;
    Gtk::DrawingArea drawarea;

    drawarea.signal_draw ().connect (sigc::bind (sigc::ptr_fun (&draw),
                                                 &drawarea));
    window.add(drawarea);
    window.show_all ();

    Gtk::Main::run(window);
    return 0;
}
```

or alternatively:

```
#include <gtkmm.h>

class LineBox : public Gtk::DrawingArea
{
protected:
    virtual bool on_draw (const Cairo::RefPtr<Cairo::Context> &ccontext);
};

bool LineBox::on_draw (const Cairo::RefPtr<Cairo::Context> &ccontext)
{
    Gtk::Allocation allocation = get_allocation();
    const int width = allocation.get_width();
    const int height = allocation.get_height();
    ccontext->set_source_rgb(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    ccontext->set_line_width(2.0);
    ccontext->move_to(0,0);
    ccontext->line_to(width, height);
    ccontext->stroke ();

    return true;
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    Gtk::Main kit(argc, argv);
    Gtk::Window window;
    LineBox drawarea;

    window.add(drawarea);
    window.show_all ();

    Gtk::Main::run(window);
    return 0;
}
```